# How to force a usage style for a singleton class

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, singleton

Suppose we have a singleton class, where the Instance function(function which returns the singleton instance of the class) has been overloaded. One version takes some parameters and does the object initializing in the class constructor, the other version does not take any parameters.

```
1.    myClass::Instance ( int x, int y );
2.    myClass::Instance ( );
```

What we want to achieve is that the user of the class should always call (1) first, and any subsequent calls should be made only to the (2). User should not be allowed to make first call to (2) and once call to (1) is done no subsequent calls to (1) be allowed.

Is it possible to achieve this without putting the burden of checking NULL pointer on the user of the class ?

Comment: Obviously, the first question should be, can you do without a Singleton ?

Comment: The singleton class *solely* makes sure that the instance is available upon request. Yours doesn't (yes it is available but you must call this function first). If the responsibility to create the instance is with the the user, then you don't have a singleton at all (which may or may not be a bad thing).

Comment: @Matthieu M. Unfortunately Singleton is needed in the situation.

Comment: @n.m. The arguments passed to the class resides in main(); HWND and HINSTANCE (winapi) and our singleton class doesn't have access to those arguments, so a singleton which saves the arguments and return the instance to the user makes sense ?

Comment: On a second thought what I just said might be incorrect, ignore it for now.

Comment: @StudentX: A Singleton is never needed, it might be used out of convenience but it is not needed. The alternative is obviously to create a class instance and pass a reference to this class to any function/method that might need it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The structure of program I am working on doesn't allow that, if we have to do that then we are talking about cross references and forward declarations. I thought singleton was a better idea as all the users will have access to this class regardless of where they are on the ladder of hierarchy. And when we have a lot of classes(independent modules) and every one wants to use this singleton class then passing reference becomes tedious .

Comment: @StudentX: I agree it can become tedious, but explicit is better than implicit in many cases. For example, what if you want to redesign your application to have two windows instead of one ? Then you will have two `HWND` handles, and depending on which is active the program should draw to one or the other. You cannot do that with a singleton... whereas it would be trivial should you be passing the handle around explicitly. Global variables (such as Singleton) hide data flow, and introduce invisible dependencies, that is why they are *Bad* (tm).

Comment: @StudentX: When working with singletons, behavior is in effect similar to keeping your data in global variables (just because you use an accessor to get to it doesn't make it less global data). This introduces hidden common state between logically unrelated modules and monolithic code. When you use dependency injection and need to alter the data, you have to alter a class (and it's dependent code). With singletons, you have to alter _all your code_ (that uses the singleton). You are exchanging short term gains (easy to write first version of code) for lack of maintainability in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you can't possibly have the compiler arbitrate this "first-call" notion at compile time (as it compiles a specific translation unit, it has no insight into whether (1) may be called from some other translation unit), so you must:

- design to restrict access to one or both overloads at compile time, and/or
- check for valid usage at run time, and/or
- make your code more tolerant of multiple calls to (1), while ensuring you'll get the behaviour you need.

There are many possible approaches which might or might not suffice:

- you could have (1) harder to access by making it protected, or private while granting friendship to specific code that will call it, leaving (2) public for convenient ongoing use by other parts of the code
- you could write the code of (1) so that after the first time it ignores any arguments and invokes (2)
- you could have assertions validating the usage at run-time, which will hopefully ensure client code complies with your conditions long before it gets into production
- you could have (1) return something that's needed to call (2), such as an object of a type that can't otherwise be created by the client, but that alone doesn't prevent (1) being called again.  That needed object might be passed to (2)'s constructor, or (2) might become a function on that object.

Comment: +1 for "design to restrict access to one or both overloads at compile time".

Answer (score 2):

In 1.
If the instance already exists, you throw an exception (std::logic_error for instance).
If not, you construct the instance with the parameters provided and return it.

In 2.
If the instance doesn't exist yet, you throw an exception (std::logic_error for instance). Then you return it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::call_once for this (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once). You will require a once_flag (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag) private member (say m_once_flag).

In 1: You wrap your implementation around a call_once with m_once_flag as first parameter.

In 2: You call 1.

The call_once will take care that the function is only executed the first time round.